# Segmenting Lungs and nodules in CT images

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am new with Image processing in Matlab, I am trying to segment LUNG and nodules from CT image. I have done initial image enhancement.

I searched lot on the same but I haven't found any relevant materials.

Trying to segment lung part from the given image; and then detecting nodules on Lung part.

[image]

Code I tried in Matlab:

```
d1 = dicomread('000000.dcm'); 
d1ca = imadjust(d1); 

d1nF = wiener2(d1ca);

d1Level  = graythresh(d1nF);
d1sBW = im2bw(d1nF,d1Level); 
sed = strel('diamon',1); 
BWfinal = imerode(d1sBW,sed);
BWfinal = imerode(BWfinal,sed);

BWoutline = bwperim(BWfinal);
Segout = d1nF;
Segout(BWoutline) = 0; 

edgePrewitt = edge(d1nF,'prewitt');
```

Result of above code:

[image]

Want results like this:

http://oi41.tinypic.com/35me7pj.jpg

http://oi42.tinypic.com/2jbtk6p.jpg

http://oi44.tinypic.com/w0kthe.jpg

http://oi40.tinypic.com/nmfaio.jpg

http://oi41.tinypic.com/2nvdrie.jpg

http://oi43.tinypic.com/2nvdnhk.jpg

I know its may be easy for experts. Please help me out.

Thank you!

Comment: Although those images are good, it would better if you posted each image as a separate .png or something rather than a screen shot of a Matlab plot so that people can download the images and play with them. Label them as well, please

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
% dp6BK.png is your original image, I downloaded directly
I = im2double(imread('dp6BK.png'));  
I=I(:,:,1);
imshow(I)


cropped = I(50:430,8:500); %% Crop region of interest   
thresholded = cropped < 0.35; %% Threshold to isolate lungs
clearThresh = imclearborder(thresholded); %% Remove border artifacts in image   
Liver = bwareaopen(clearThresh,100); %% Remove objects less than 100 pixels
Liver1 = imfill(Liver,'hole'); % fill in the vessels inside the lungs
figure,imshow(Liver1.*cropped)
```

What you will get:

[image]

Comment: Thanks you save my day.. `nodules` please look second part of question

Comment: try tuning the parameters in the code. I would change two lines:  thresholded = cropped > 0.75; Liver = bwareaopen(clearThresh,10);

Comment: @lennon310 how to perform segmentation of lungs  in python programing? Same output as above I want but using python

Answer (score 14):

**The following is not a Matlab answer!** However, **OpenCV** and **Matlab** share many features in common, and I'm sure you will be able to translate this C++ code to Matlab with no problems.

For more information about the methods being called, check the [OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/master/modules/refman.html).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>    

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
// Load input image (colored, i.e. 3-channel)
cv::Mat input = cv::imread(argv[1]);
if (input.empty())
{
    std::cout << "!!! failed imread()" << std::endl;
    return -1;
}   

// Convert input image to grayscale (1-channel)
cv::Mat grayscale = input.clone();
cv::cvtColor(input, grayscale, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
```

What **grayscale** looks like:

[image]

```
// Erode & Dilate to remove noises and improve the result of the next operation (threshold)
int erosion_type = cv::MORPH_RECT; // MORPH_RECT, MORPH_CROSS, MORPH_ELLIPSE
int erosion_size = 3;
cv::Mat element = cv::getStructuringElement(erosion_type, 
                                            cv::Size(2 * erosion_size + 1, 2 * erosion_size + 1), 
                                            cv::Point(erosion_size, erosion_size));

cv::erode(grayscale, grayscale, element);
cv::dilate(grayscale, grayscale, element);
```

What **grayscale** looks like after morphological operations:

[image]

```
// Threshold to segment the area of the lungs
cv::Mat thres;
cv::threshold(grayscale, thres, 80, 150, cv::THRESH_BINARY);
```

What **thres** looks like:

[image]

```
    // Find the contours of the lungs in the thresholded image
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
cv::findContours(thres, contours, cv::RETR_LIST, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);


// Fill the areas of the lungs with BLUE for better visualization   
cv::Mat lungs = input.clone();      
for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
{
    std::vector<cv::Point> cnt = contours[i];
    double area = cv::contourArea(cv::Mat(cnt));        

    if (area > 15000 && area < 35000)
    {
        std::cout << "* Area: " << area << std::endl;
        cv::drawContours(lungs, contours, i, cv::Scalar(255, 0, 0), 
                         CV_FILLED, 8, std::vector<cv::Vec4i>(), 0, cv::Point() );
    }           
}
```

What **lungs** looks like:

[image]

```
// Using the image with blue lungs as a mask, we create a new image containing only the lungs
cv::Mat blue_mask = cv::Mat::zeros(input.size(), CV_8UC1);
cv::inRange(lungs, cv::Scalar(255, 0, 0), cv::Scalar(255, 0, 0), blue_mask);    
cv::Mat output;
input.copyTo(output, blue_mask);
```

What **output** looks like:

[image]

At this point you have the lungs isolated in the image and can proceed to execute other filter operations to isolate the nodules.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, its really  excellent answer - I am translating it into Matlab and I will accept.

Comment: `nodules` please look second part of question

Comment: Please look at the end of my answer. This is to get you started and it's not meant to be a complete solution. To filter the **nodules** you will have to continue to experiment with whatever filters Matlab offers. Filtering the nodules is $$$. ;)